# Neo4j Web Admin how to display relationship properties?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I've generated a Neo4j graph and created visualization of the graph using the 'Style' rules on   'Data Browser'. I was able to display the properties of the Nodes. It looks like the style rules can only be applied to Nodes. However I want to display (visualize on data browser) the properties on the relationship. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

I read through the Neo4j documentation and also searched in the Neo4j forums but had no luck.

I appreciate any help.

TIA

For example:

```
              (is a)
(Josh) --------------------> (Male)
       (demographic=gender)
       (created=09/25/12)
```

Where demographic, created are properties of the relationship 'is a'.

Comment: I don't think you can tweak that in the web admin--seems to only allow for node styles.

Comment: If not through web admin, is there another way to achieve this w/ neo4j tools or otherwise like say Gephi or other tools?

Comment: you might want to check some universal data visualisation, like: http://thejit.org/demos/  i personally used the hypertree representation, was fast enough but dont know whether it supports relations parameters by default. but the code is open sourced and i easily tweak it as i need to.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you extended the question to available options, not just Webadmin:
The Neo folks put up a side about visualization options: http://www.neo4j.org/develop/visualize
For your use case, try Neoclipse https://github.com/neo4j/neoclipse/downloads
it allows to specify which properties to display on nodes and relationship (be sure to enable the filters in the Graph Database View or the preferences won't have any effect). It look similar to the webadmin, but can be customized more.